# Virtual Instance of a C compiler on client browser

Tags: c, gcc

Is there a way I can create a virtual instance of gcc compiler on the client browser when the client opens my website??
By doing so, I can directly pass the user .c file as argument to my compiler instance and then execute it without having to make a POST call to server and execute the file there???

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't understand what you mean. The client shouldn't be compiling anything in the browser, that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Coltin :- 
Online programming contests pass the user file to the server where they execute it. If there are millions of users, then the server efficiency will decrease.  
So, if there is a way that i can create a virtual instance of my gcc compiler dynamically, so that i don't have to make server calls to execute the file.
If there is still a doubt, let me know

Comment: I think you might be better off just letting each contestant tell you weather or not they won the contest.  To get any reasonable amount of performance out of a browser hosted compiler it would need to be written in javascript or better yet java virtual machine (or possibly other pluggin languages).

Comment: I'm entirely failing to see where the problem is. It should be no major problem to compile the typical program for a contest. Those are rarely over a thousand lines, and typically contained in a single Translation Unit. Furthermore, compiling inputs from millions of users is embarrasingly parallel (no shared bottleneck). Execution could potentially be a bottleneck, but an online contest should fail the program if execution takes too long anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally I userstood your question to be targeting the native platform on which the browser is running:

> Consider that Browsers may be running
>   on many different platforms,
>   operatinng systems and processor
>   architectures. Compiling C in the way
>   you describe might be technically
>   doable, but practically infeasible.

I was basing "practically infeasible" on the difficulty of supporting the plethora of widely used browser platforms.

Now I understand that you are thinking more on the lines of targeting a virtual environment. I'll amend practically infeasible to "a large amount of work".

If I understand your intent it is to run a C compiler which emits, shall we say, x86 compiled code and executes it. So to do that we need an emulation of the x86 environment in, say, JavaScript. What's more I think your intent is that the conmpiler itself execute in this environment, so that you can re-use gcc. So you'll need to emulate a file-system too. It's "obvious" that this could be done, but it really is a lot of work. Is it really worth it?

Competition code is small (I guess) even with lots of programmers the number of simultaneous compiles can't be so huge with a decent queued request system, a touch of Ajax, and a bit of back-end scaling how costly is it to support the expected population? What's the ratio of developers to back end systems?

Anyway, if I were to address this problem I'd go for taking the code for an opensource browser and melding in the gcc code. Produce a compiler/browser hybrid. Give that to the developers and tell them "Use this and get zippy compilation speeds, or use your own browser and join the queue."

Comment: Of course you don't make a native binary for the local machine. You compile the C to run on a virtual machine written in javascript. Of course writing a C compiler in javascript will be a bit of work.. :-)

Comment: An alternative (much easier but slower) would be writing a x86 virtual machine in javascript and running gcc on that...

Comment: @djna :-
Why is it practically infeasible??
i guess you didn't get the whole idea of what i am trying to do.

Comment: Can i create an instance of my gcc compiler and send it to the client at the time of loading.

Comment: @Silver Spoon - I was a tad hasty, amended my answer.

Comment: @djna :-   "Anyway, if I were to address this problem I'd go for taking the code for an opensource browser and melding in the gcc code. Produce a compiler/browser hybrid. Give that to the developers and tell them "Use this and get zippy compilation speeds, or use your own browser and join the queue."...........Can you elaborate on this a little bit...I am unable to understand that.

Comment: @djna :- And I dnt really need to emulate my file system the way i am thinking about it now...I might be wrong. Can you elaborate a little bit on the need to emulate the file system.

Comment: File-systems: compilation will reference headers, need to read files. Browser may not permit access to native file system, or it might use different file naming conventions. 
Your own browser: If the browser includes the gcc code it's running natively on the developer's machine, no limits to what it can do. No need to virtualise anything.

Comment: GCC running on an emulator running as javascript or on a JVM in a browser is going to be very painful for all but very small C source files.  I'd bet that the memory usage of this would be sky high and the garbage collection would rarely know that it could free memory.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to use GCC as it is written for this.  AT BEST, you could accomplish something simalar if you had a compiler written in Java that targeted the JVM and could be ran as an applet.  I don't know what it would take to get something like this working but, I suspect it would take a bit work to get it up and going.  As far as I know nothing currently exist that does this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using a **jsLinux** in background? There the making process can run in the virtual machine. Communication could be done by extending the clipboard transfer, perhaps into multiple pipes...

I would be interested in javascript based gcc solutions, too.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).